# Pyramind Plot using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-col

[image]
I need help in removing/converting the negative values in the x-axis of the pyramid plot.
I was able to build the pyramid through https://walker-data.com/census-r/exploring-us-census-data-with-visualization.html subheading 4.5.2. I keep getting an error saying function not found: number_format.

I think the scale_x_continuous is where I'd be able to change the - sign but returns an error everytime

Comment: How are negaitve count values possible on the x axis? Could you please provide more info and the code so far?

Comment: The function `number_format` is from the `scales` package. Hence try with adding `library(scales)` or use `scales::number_format`. Note however that `number_format` is superseded. Therefore it would be best to use `scales::label_number` instead.

Comment: https://walker-data.com/census-r/exploring-us-census-data-with-visualization.html this link provides all the details I can possibly give and it's the same codes I used to build  the pyramid plot. It's the negative values for the female gender I want to format not to show the negative sign in the axis as in the screenshot provided

Comment: @stefan thanks so much for the help. I used ```scale_x_continuous(labels = label_number(style_negative = "parents"``` and it worked fine but it's placing the negative values in bracket e.g (4000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from the context of the plot, I am assuming that you don't want to convert the values themselves, but rather convert the x-axis so that the male and female sides of the pyramid are mirrored?

In which case, you can use `abs`. The function `abs(x)` computes the absolute value of x, which would remove the negative sign from your data's values.

Without seeing a reproducible example of your code (which should be included when you ask questions like this on Stack Overflow, see the package [{reprex}](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) for help with this), it's a little difficult to be sure exactly what you need to change to make the code work, but I think you should be on the right track with `scale_x_continuous`.

With regard to the error that you're receiving, it suggests that you haven't imported the library for that function, [{scales}](https://scales.r-lib.org/), as suggested by stefan in the comments (and as suggested, `scales:::label_number` has superseded `scales:::number_format`, so you should use the former).

If you're using the `scale_x_continuous` code from the second plot in [Section 4.5.2](https://walker-data.com/census-r/exploring-us-census-data-with-visualization.html#designing-and-styling-the-population-pyramid) of the link you have shared:

```
utah_pyramid +
  scale_x_continuous(
    labels = ~ number_format(scale = .001, suffix = "k")(abs(.x)),
    limits = 140000 * c(-1, 1)
  )
```

The `number_format` function  isn't the part of the code that is producing the absolute values, it is converting the scale of the values to thousands. It is the `abs(.x)` part that is removing the negative sign.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. ```scale_x_continuous(labels = abs)``` worked really fine